# delphi google calendar Api event insert

Tags: rest, delphi, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am trying to insert an event into my google calendar using the delphi REST controls.

This is the code so far:

```
procedure TForm1.TestGoogleRestParams;
var
  i: Integer;
  jsonObjEventResource,jsonObjStart,jsonObjEnd: TJSONObject;
begin
  try
    jsonObjEventResource:=TJSONObject.Create();
    jsonObjStart:=TJSONObject.Create();
    jsonObjEnd:=TJSONObject.Create();

    jsonObjEventResource.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('summary','test'));
    jsonObjEventResource.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('description','Testing'));
    jsonObjEventResource.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('id',LowerCase('06824945162F4204BFDC041AE1BBAE85')));

    jsonObjStart.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('date',FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',Now)));

    jsonObjEventResource.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('start',jsonObjStart));

    jsonObjEnd.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('date',FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',Now)));

    jsonObjEventResource.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('end',jsonObjEnd));

    jsonObjEventResource.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('guestsCanInviteOthers',TJSONBool. Create(false)));
    jsonObjEventResource.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('visibility','private'));

    mem_Test.Lines.Add(TJson.Format(jsonObjEventResource));
    //mem_Test.Lines.Add(jsonObjEventResource.ToJSON);
    RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    RESTRequest.Body.ClearBody;
    RESTRequest.AddBody(jsonObjEventResource);
    RESTRequest.Execute;
  finally
    //jsonObjEventResource.Free;
    //jsonObjStart.Free;
    //jsonObjEnd.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The Scope I am using is: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.
BaseURL : https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3
ResourceURI : calendars/primary/events

I do get an access token and a refresh token but I cannot Post the Request. This is the error i recieve:

```
{
  "error":
  {
    "errors":
    [
            {
        "domain":"global",
        "reason":"required",
        "message":"Login Required",
        "locationType":"header",
        "location":"Authorization"
      }
    ]
,
    "code":401,
    "message":"Login Required"
  }
}
```

With the following uri: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events`

How can i fix this?

If I don't call this method and just call `RESTRequest.Execute;` I get a list of all my existing events.

Answer (score 0):

> ":"Invalid Credentials"

Means that the client id and client secret that you are using are incorrect.   You should download a new file from Google Developer console and try again.

Option 2:

Try authenticating the user it could be that the access token has expired and needs to be refreshed

Comment: Are you sure? I can get a list of all my events i just dont know how to insert an event

Comment: Thats what it means are you sure you dont have your code mixed up one call sends the correct credentials another is doing it wrong.

Comment: im using the RESTDemo as a framework to test the code. if i leave out the call to the `TestGoogleRestParams` I get the list of events.

Comment: try option 2 my Delphi is really rusty trying to pick though your code

Comment: I do get authenticated before i call this code and the token takes an hour to expire